# Formatting Data in a Dialog Box

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, dialog

I am a newby to Google Sheets and Google Apps Script.

I have been looking for hours figure out how to display the data I am getting from a Range of Cells in a column format. I may need some sort to CSS to display this Properly. I would like 2 Column if possible. Currently what I get is a line of text with the data separated with commas!

In addition am also trying to get the data till the next empty row.

```
  A : B : C : D
1 45  67  79  80
2 68  66  49  19
3
4 47  68  59  81
```

If the data set looks like this in the sheet I want to get the data till the third row. I have found a code (below) but it gets all the data till the last row in the whole sheet, not the next empty cell.

```
var Avals = ss.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var Alast = Avals.filter(String).length;
```

This is the code I am working with so far. I am going to continue to trawl the web to see if their are ant other solutions.

```
function errorPrompt(missvar) {
      var missVar = "test";
      var ccurr = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(2,2).getValues();
      var exchangename = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(3,1,4,2).getValues();

       var htmlOutput = HtmlService
         .createHtmlOutput(exchangename)
         .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
         .setWidth(400)
         .setHeight(300);
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, ccurr +' Detail');
    }
```

Comment: Don't have experience with scripts. But `=ARRAYFORMULA(MATCH(1,(--ISBLANK(A1:A50)),0))` give the first blank row.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will return an array of values from the top of your data down to but not including the first empty row. The return array is an array of rows.

```
function getDataDownToTheFirstEmptyRow()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++)
  {
    if(!vA[i].join(''))
    {
      return(sh.getRange(1,1,i,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues());
    }
  }
}
```